# what does (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b exactly do in the Functor class

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
       pure :: a -> f a
       (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

From my understanding, it takes a function f, where another function `(a -> b)` as its argument, returns a function `f`. Applying `f` to `a` then returns a function `f` and apply `f` to `b`.

Here is an example:

```
Prelude> (+) <$> Just 2 <*> Just 3
Just 5
```

But I don't quite understand how it works.

I guess `(+)` should be `f`, `Just 2` and `Just 3` should be `a` and `b` respectively. Then what is `(a -> b)`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "...do in *Applicative* class"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> From my understanding, it takes a function f...

Unfortunately this is incorrect. In this case, `f` is a type, not a function. Specifically, `f` is a "higher-kinded type" with kind `* -> *`. The type `f` is the functor.

In this case, `f` is `Maybe`. So we can rewrite the function types, specializing them for `Maybe`:

```
pure :: a -> Maybe a
(<*>) :: Maybe (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

It starts to become a bit clearer once you get this far. There are a couple different possible definitions for `pure`, but only one that makes sense:

```
pure = Just
```

The operator `x <$> y` is the same as `pure x <*> y`, so if you write out:

```
(+) <$> Just 2 <*> Just 3
```

Then we can rewrite it as:

```
pure (+) <*> pure 2 <*> pure 3
```

Although this technically has a more general type. Working with the functor laws, we know that `pure x <*> pure y` is the same as `pure (x y)`, so we get

```
pure ((+) 2) <*> pure 3
pure ((+) 2 3)
pure (2 + 3)
```

In this case, we `a` and `b` are the *types* but since `<*>` appears twice they actually have different types in each case.

In the first `<*>`, `a` is `Int` and `b` is `Int -> Int`.
In the second `<*>`, both `a` and `b` are `Int`. (Technically you get generic versions of `Int` but that's not really important to the question.)

Comment: The operator x <$> y is the same as pure x <*> y. Is it a typo or exactly what you mean? I think it might be x<*>y, isn't it?

Comment: No, there's no typo. `x <$> y` is the same as `pure x <*> y`.

Comment: Worth mentioning is this; `fmap :: a->b`, while `<*> :: f (a -> b)`. A nice result of the Applicative typeclass is that you can have a function taking multiple arguments and apply them by using repeated `<*>`, e.g `pure f <*> a <*> b <*> c <*> d .. `. Since fmap accepts a pure function, you can not apply multiple `fmap`s and get it working.

Comment: “In this case, `f` is a type, not a function” – I'd say it's closer to being a function than a type. An _injective type-level function_ it is, aka type constructor.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: That is incorrect, in this case `f` is actually a type, and it is not a function. There is no logical way that `f` can be "closer" to being a function. It is not necessary that `f` be a type constructor… in fact, there are many functors which are not type constructors, such as `Either String`. In this case, `f` is a *type variable* with kind `* -> *`. It is incorrect to equate type constructors with "type-level functions", and recall that while functions in Haskell are values, likewise higher-kinded types are types.

Comment: @DietrichEpp it can't be a type since it doesn't classify a family of (runtime) values. It _is_ a function (though not a Haskell function) because you can apply it to something (a type) and get something well-defined back (another type). You might call it a type-level value (in the same way a Haskell function is a Haskell value), but not a type. A type is something that has kind `Type` (formerly known as `*`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout: That definition of "type" is the problem then, in Haskell types are not limited to the types of runtime values but include types of other kinds. Please refer to the Haskell report, this usage appears throughout, especially chapter 4.

Comment: Yes, but that definition is the correct one, whereas the Haskell report is being sloppy with terminology. (And yes, the `type` keyword is sloppy too.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: In mathematics and computer science you will have to get used to the fact that the same word can mean different things in different contexts and fields, and different groups of people may have their own standard terminology which conflicts with the terminology you learned somewhere else. The idea that there is a single correct definition for "type" is unfounded. Please leave your personal preferences out of this, if you want to change community standards for terminology this is not the place for it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: If you find the terminology in the Haskell report sloppy or inconsistent you may wish to write up a defect report about it.

Comment: Maybe that should be done. The thing is, originally the Haskell report seems to have envisioned kinds to be more a compiler implementation detail that shouldn't bother the programmer much. You'd basically just distinct “value level” and “type level” and not worry too much that some of the things in type-level land wouldn't actually be types. But then things turned out different, Haskell went towards dependent typing, and that makes it necessary to be a bit more precise and actually mean _type_ when you say “type”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Haskell does not have dependent typing, and I'm not aware of any language extension that adds dependent typing. The reason why "type" seems imprecise is because the phrase "actually mean type when you say 'type'" contains an equivocation, and there's an easy way to avoid equivocation here--you can avoid equivocation by using standard terminology. It seems like you are deliberately avoiding standard terminology and purposefully using non-standard definitions for your terms... using non-standard terminology will naturally make statements seem ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Applicative functors were introduced to Haskell *as applicative style programming ["Idioms"](http://strictlypositive.org/Idiom.pdf)*. Unpacking this phrase, we have "applicative style programming"; which is just application of functions to arguments. We also have "idioms", or phrases in a language which have a special meaning. For example "raining cats and dogs" is an idiom for raining very heavily. Putting them together, applicative functors are function applications with special meaning.

Take for example, following Dietrich Epp's lead, `anApplication` defined by a function,

```
anApplication = f a
  where
    f = (+2)
    a = 3
```

and, `anIdiomaticApplication`, defined with idiomatic application,

```
anIdiomaticApplication = f <*> a
   where 
     f = Just (+2)
     a = Just 3
```

The top level structure of these definitions are similar. The difference? The first has a space--normal function application--and the second has `<*>`--idiomatic function application. This illustrates how `<*>` facilitates applicative style: just use `<*>` in place of a space.

The application, `<*>`, is idiomatic because it carries a meaning other than just pure function application. By way of exposition, in `anIdiomaticApplication` we have something like this:

```
 f <*> a :: Maybe (Int -> Int) <*> Maybe Int
```

Here, the `<*>` in the type is used to represent a type level function* that corresponds to the signature of the real `<*>`. To the type-`<*>` we apply the type arguments for `f` and `a` (respectively `Maybe (Int -> Int)` and `Maybe Int`). After application we have

```
 f <*> a :: Maybe Int
```

As an intermediate step, we can imagine something like

```
 f <*> a :: Maybe ((Int -> Int) _ Int)
```

With `_` being the type level stand-in for regular function application.

At this point we can finally see the *idiom-ness* called out. `f <*> a` is like a normal function application, `(Int -> Int) _ Int`, in the `Maybe` context/idiom. So, `<*>` is just function application that happens within a certain context.

In parting, I'll emphasize that understanding `<*>` is only partially understanding its use. We can understand that `f <*> a` is just function application which some extra idiomatic meaning. Due to the Applicative laws, we can also assume that idiomatic application will be somehow sensible.

Don't be surprised, however, if you look at `<*>` and get confused since there is so little there. We must also be versed in the various Haskell Idioms. For instance, in the `Maybe` idiom either the function or value may not be present, in which case the output will be `Nothing`. There are of course, many others, but getting familiar with just `Either a` and `State s` should model a wide variety of the different kinds.

*Something like this could actually be made with a closed type family (untested)

```
type family IdmApp f a where
   IdmApp (f (a->b)) a = f b
```